how to apply union by name in sparksql，not union or union all
When i run query in old sparksql version like
select * from 
    (select 10 as student_type,'henry' as student_name
      union 
     select 'tom' as student_name,90 as student_type,
    );

then i get result like this:



student_type
student_name




10
henry


tom
90



it looks like in sparksql，'UNION' fail to match the columns by this method;
however, in spark dataframe, i can union two dataframe by using 'unionByName'.
so how do i use syntax like 'unionByName' in sparksql?
The Expectation is:



student_type
student_name




10
henry


90
tom




You can sort column names before union them
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SORT_ARRAY(ARRAY(*)) 
        FROM (SELECT 10 AS student_type,'henry' AS student_name)
    UNION 
    SELECT SORT_ARRAY(ARRAY(*)) 
        FROM (SELECT 'tom' AS student_name, 90 AS student_type)
);

Sample run:
spark-sql (default)> SELECT *
                   > FROM (
                   >     SELECT SORT_ARRAY(ARRAY(*)) 
                   >         FROM (SELECT 10 AS student_type,'henry' AS student_name)
                   >     UNION 
                   >     SELECT SORT_ARRAY(ARRAY(*)) 
                   >         FROM (SELECT 'tom' AS student_name, 90 AS student_type)
                   > );
["10","henry"]
["90","tom"]
Time taken: 0.11 seconds, Fetched 2 row(s)

